# Detail view context

Tags: python, django

how can i get all images of item into context
i tried {% for image in item.images.all %} in template but it doesn't work.
i dunno how to filter it , ty for ur answer

*models*

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True)
    size = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('single_product', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_sale(self):
        price = int(self.price * (100 - self.discount) / 100)

        return price

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='images')
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name
```

*views*

```
class ItemDetail(DetailView):
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'item'
    template_name = 'essense/single-product-details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Please show the template.

Comment: Normally `item.images.all` should work. So I think there is something wrong with how you *render* the images.

Comment: <div class="single_product_thumb clearfix">
        <div class="product_thumbnail_slides owl-carousel">
            {% for image in item.images.all %}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="" width="360" height="539">
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. In your template tag `{% for image in item.images.all %}`, `image` refers to an instance of your ItemImage model. You need to reference the ImageField within that model, which you've named `images`. So, instead of
`src="{{ image.url }}"` use `src="{{ image.images.url }}"`

````
<div className="single_product_thumb clearfix">
    <div className="product_thumbnail_slides owl-carousel"> 
        {% for image in item.images.all %} <img
            src="{{ image.images.url }}" alt="" width="360" height="539"> 
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>```
````